# Get Service not being called in Angular 6, its not showing even in the network calls

Tags: angular, http, get, rxjs, angular6

I am using Angular 6, and trying to use a GET service in my application for getting IP from the server, but my GET service is not being called. I have tried various way but no help.

the service is not showing in the network call as well..

below is the service call for the same

**Get Function :**

```js
get(reqUrl: string, params?: any, reqOpts?: any) { 
    return this.http.get(reqUrl, reqOpts); 
}
```

**Service Call Function :**

```js
this._api.get(reqUrl)
    .subscribe(
        response => {},
        err => {}
    );
```

Please help me on this ...

Comment: Share the code on how you call the method in your service and the code for the service itself

Comment: Hi @C_Ogoo, thanks for the reply.. 

 get(reqUrl: string, params?: any, reqOpts?: any) {
    return this.http.get(reqUrl, reqOpts);
  }

Comment: just created a get function and called as above

Comment: Please update your question with the code for both the service and the component

Answer (score 2):

What this looks like is that you're not calling subscribe on the `get` call.

Your `get` method returns an observable:

```
get(reqUrl: string, params?: any, reqOpts?: any) { 
  return this.http.get(reqUrl, reqOpts);
}
```

So in you component, you have to call `.subscribe()` on the returned variable.

**Your component**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.get()
    .subscribe((res) => {
      // the response will be available here
    })
}
```

Observables are lazy by default. This means, without calling `.subscribe()` your code doesn't get executed.

Comment: Hi @C_Ogoo, 
have updated the question... and using the subscribe call as above.. Please suggest in any further changes need to be made

Comment: Please post the full code for the component and the service